# Find a Lipschitz constant for the function $f(t,x)=x(\sin t -x^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, lipschitz-functions

The function is bounded on t from $0$ to $2\pi$ And $\vert x \vert \le M$

See that $\vert f(t,x)-f(t,x')\vert \le L\vert x-x'\vert$

I have taken the derivative with respect to x, but don't know what to do from here, does it suffice to say that the Lipschitz constant will be an arbitrary M^3?

Any help regarding multivariate Lipschitz functions would be appreciated

Comment: Do you understand why it is useful to consider the partial derivative with respect to $x$? If not: take a look at the Mean Value Theorem. It tells you what you have to do, to arrive at a Lipschitz constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$f(t,x_2)-f(t,x_1)=x_2(\sin(t)-x_2^2)-x_1(\sin(t)-x_1^2)=\sin(t)(x_2-x_1)-(x_2^3-x_1^3)=\sin(t)(x_2-x_1)-(x_2-x_1)(x_2^2+x_1x_2+x_1^2)$$
does this help you?
thus we have $$|f(t,x_2)-f(t,x_1)|\le |x_2-x_1|\left(\left|\sin(t)\right|+|x_2^2+x_1x_2+x_1^2|\right)$$

Comment: So then this $\vert f(t,x1)-f(t,x2)\vert \le L \vert x1 -x2 \vert$ right? And the $x1$ and $x2$ can be divided out to give the polynomial and the sin function. The sine function is bounded by 1, would you then evaluate $x1$ as it approaches $x2$?

Comment: for $x$ you have $$|x|\le M$$

Comment: the Lipschitz constant must be a number

Comment: Taking the partial derivative with respect to x then would yield $-4x^2$ as $x1$ approaches $x2$, thus would we have $\vert 4*M\vert \le L$ for the constant?

Comment: i would write $$(1+3M)$$ with $$M>0$$